# In C# Outlook VSTO, is there a way to change users view to the calendar view and highlight a specific day?

Tags: c#, calendar, outlook, vsto

I want to create a button in an outlook VSTO addin that when clicked, will show the users outlook calendar week view and i want to pass in a date that will drive what week it show.

Is this possible in C# outlook vsto to programatically changes the users view?

Comment: Outlook already has such functionality. Why do you want to invent the wheel?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - appreciate what you are saying but i am actually doing this as part of a number of programatic actions.  I just simplified my situation to ask an "isolated" question.  The rest of the context of my situation is not required for the question

Comment: Yes, you can control calendar view programmatically obtaining the `CalendarView` object through `CurrentView` property of `Explorer` object.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new button and on its on click event use the [CurrentView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861617.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the Explorer class.

Information from MSDN states regarding Views:

> The View object allows you to create customizable views that allow you
>   to better sort, group and ultimately view data of all different types.
>   There are a variety of different view types that provide the
>   flexibility needed to create and maintain your important data.
>
> - The table view type (olTableView) allows you to view data in a simple    field-based table.
> - The Calendar view type (olCalendarView) allows you to view data in a    calendar format.
> - The card view type (olCardView) allows you to view data in a series    of cards. Each card displays the information contained by the item
>     and can be sorted.
> - The icon view type (olIconView) allows you to view data as icons,    similar to a Windows folder or explorer.
> - The timeline view type (olTimelineView) allows you to view data as it    is received in a customizable linear time line.

You'll want to use `olCalendarView` which is defiened and customized using the View object's XML property. The XML property allows you to create and set a customized XML schema that defines the various features of a view

Then you can set the date you want (in case your current view is calendar view) -

```
Outlook.Explorer olkExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer();
DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);

if (olkExplorer.CurrentView is Outlook.CalendarView)
{
    Outlook.CalendarView olkCalendarView = olkExplorer.CurrentView as Outlook.CalendarView;

    olkCalendarView.GoToDate(selectedDate);
}
```

I hope it supports your question.